# Convert OData enabled api controller to format output json as TitleCase instead of camel case

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

OData endpoints are serializing json as camel case, but other non OData endpoints are serializing as Titlecase. We want all Titlecase json output.

I've researched about changing the serialization settings for the OData sterilizer, but documentation is minimal. The startup is already specifying the default contract resolver, but OData isn't using it apparently.